# PLACEHOLDER Stack Overflow App

Tags: app, placeholder, stackoverflow

[image]

### StackOverflow desktop app (MacOS, Windows, Linux)

**IMPORTANT:** This app is under development. This is a hobby project so no deadlines, no commercial.

- Fast, clean, and distraction-free UI
- Better wysiwyg editor
- Native notifications
- Cross-platform
- and more...

**Technology stack:**

- Electron
- React + TypeScript
- mobx-state-tree
- ChakraUI

**Stay tuned:**

- Please, start a repo [GitHub](https://github.com/Maqsim/stackoverflow-app)
- https://www.twitch.tv/jott1

**Interesting to test this app?**

- Ping me here [maxdiachenko.com](https://maxdiachenko.com)

### Some screens (11 May, 2022)

[image]

[image]
App launching

[image]
Question details screen

[image]
Question details screen 2

[image]
Bountied questions screen

[image]
Profile screen

[image]
My tags screen

[image]
All tags screen

[image]
Dropdowns

#### MacOS

TBD

#### Windows

TBD

#### Linux

TBD

Comment: This app is under development. Why? Because MacOS. &c. :)

Comment: @Max It's nothing!